# Reading a c++ class object

Tags: c++

For Reading a class object (here "**arts**" is the name of an object). I have to follow the following code
filin is a input and output stream.

```
filin.write((char*)&arts,sizeof(arts));
filin.read((char*)&arts,sizeof(arts));
```

Can you explain these.

1. Why do we type caste by adding (char *) and why to a character pointer.
2. Why add & symbol before arts?.
3. why add sizeof(arts) at the end?.

Comment: search Pointer's Mathematics in google

Comment: @Saurabh No, that’s not helping, even once you correct the search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do we type caste by adding (char *) and why to a character pointer.

`char` is a wrong name. It’s a lie – it should be called `byte` because that’s what it is: a *byte*. The [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) functions you’re using work on a byte buffer – this is to make them generic, i.e. work with arbitrary types (although that’s a also lie).

> Why add & symbol before arts?

The `&` takes the memory address of an object. By writing `(char*) &obj` we are effectively getting (the address to) a byte buffer that is underlying a given object – in other words, the object’s representation in bytes.

> why add sizeof(arts) at the end?.

`sizeof(obj)` tells us how large `obj` is in memory – i.e. how many bytes it takes up in the byte buffer. Given the start address (see previous point) and the size, we completely characterise an object’s physical existence in memory and we can use this to transfer an object from main memory into a file and vice versa.

However, as I’ve said before that’s kind of a lie. C++ actually has many types of objects which do not support this kind of copying their memory around, because these objects actually make assumptions about the memory they live in. In the simplest case they contain a pointer member which, after copying the byte representation of the object, still points to the old location and is thus no longer useful:

```
struct some_class {
    some_class* self;

    some_class() : self(this) { }
};
```

This class has a member – `self` – which points to itself. Copying an instance of this class bytewise would destroy this identity and render the object useless (after copying the `self` member of the copy would *still* point to the original, not the copy).

This kind of byte-wise copying is also called a *shallow copy* – as opposed to a *deep* copy which would copy the afore-mentioned pointer correctly.

The code you’ve shown is not generally safe in C++. In fact, there are even more issues with it than I’ve so far alluded to, and in most cases there are better alternatives for the (de)serialisation of objects.

Comment: May be this is a dumb question.If we create a character pointer char *p,a='b'; p=&a;
Does 'p' stores anything(I guessed address of a, but in that case I am afraid if the address could be of 1 byte size?).

Comment: @boywholived Yes, `p` stores the address to `a`. `p` is a variable of the type “poiner to `char` ”. And a pointer variable always has the *same* size regardless of the object that it refers to – and it’s not 1 byte (that would only allow for 256 different addresses on most systems, which is the values expressible in 8 bits). A pointer most commonly takes up 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the system).

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions:

1 - `write` and `read` take a `char` pointer (`char *`). This means that `write` and `read` work byte by byte and read or write exactly as many bytes as the given by the second argument of the function.

2- `&` is `address of`. Which means that you are taking the address of `arts`, then you are casting the address to a `char` pointer as `(char*)&arts`.

3 - `sizeof()` returns the length of its parameter (length refers to **size occupied by an instance in the memory**). In this case, you get the size of `arts` and tell `write` and `read`, how many bits to `write` or `read`.

Comment: Thank you sir. A small doubt: is sizeof(art) always fixed value?. Or does that change when the values of data members change?.

Comment: Same comment as for the other, now deleted answer (hey, this one is almost a copy paste): 1. why? 2. why?  3. What’s “length”?

Comment: sizeof(art) doesn't change when the values of the members change.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `&` operator takes the pointer of your arts object. Assuming you object `arts` is of type `Foo`:

```
Foo arts;
```

then `&arts` is of type `Foo*`.

The method `write()` in your code seems to deal with arrays of bytes (usually needed to transfer over the network, or to write to a file), so it uses pointer to `char` (written as `char*`) because the type `char` has the size of 1 byte, (well, in any platform I know of), so if you add or subtract from a char pointer, you advance or rewind the pointer by that amount of bytes (in C++, pointer arithmetic is done in steps multiple of the byte size of the object).

When you cast from `Foo*` to `char*` you are effectively telling the compiler to treat that pointer in multiples of 1 byte, not multiple of the full size of your object. That is customary practice for functions that deals with byte arrays, as seems to be the case in your `write()` and  `read()` functions.

Finally, in the first parameter, you pass simply a pointer, a memory address. So, for the function `write()` to know how many bytes it must read from your pointer, you must pass in the length of your object (the second parameter). The operator `sizeof(arts)` translates, at compile time, to the size in bytes of the object `arts` (it can take the type, too, so writing `sizeof Foo` would be equivalent, if `Foo` is the type of `arts`).

Comment: `char` **always** has the size 1 byte, by definition. I think the whole point about the size of the `char` type and pointer arithmetic is a red herring. What’s relevant is that the functions work on a byte buffer.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to start from second question. 
Operator & simply returns you a pointer to the object in memory. Then we cast the pointer to arts object to the pointer to char. Char have the size of the smallest addressable memory unit on particular machine, it can be 8 bits (most common), less and more. We also call it "byte".  And at last we call sizeof function, which returns size of the object, represented as number of the smallest memory units (chars in our case) needed to store that object.
After that function receiving pointer to some place in memory and the number of bytes to write or read. Everything it need's to know.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted stores an object in a stream and later retrieves it from the stream. Let's break the code into pieces.

```
filin.write((char*)&arts,sizeof(arts));
```

First of all, let's inspect the signature of write method. I guess, that it looks similar to the following:

```
stream::write(char * input, int size)
```

So the stream object takes a pointer to some place in memory, takes `size` bytes from there and stores.

Now, let's compare your command to this signature. `input` is (char*)&arts. You have an `arts` object of some type and you want to store it. `input` has to be a pointer to place in memory, where the object is stored, so you retrieve it by using a `&` operator: `&arts`. However, the method expects the `input` to be a `char*` (meaning more less a pointer to byte, char is used not only when you want to process a character, but also where you want to process bytes), but your pointer is not a `char *`. This is why a typecast is made: pointer to `arts` type is converted to pointer to a `char *`. Its value remains the same, but now compiler knows, that *you* know what you are doing.

Next, there's a size parameter telling the stream class how many bytes to consume. Since you want to store an arts object, a `sizeof(arts)` is called to verify its size.